# Icon font files in gitignore

Tags: git, gruntjs, gulp, icon-fonts

I use gulp to create an icon font out of *.svg files.

Should the generated font files (font.eot, font.ttf, font.woff) be gitignored?

Comment: Yes, they are build artifacts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they are part of your build, meaning they are generated in `build/Release`, they are ignored by default, since a [typical Node `.gitignore` file](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Node.gitignore#L28) ignores that folder.

More generally, if you can regenerate an artifact, it is worth considering ignoring it.